# Loading Data into marklogic from MySql

Tags: mysql-workbench, marklogic, document-database

How to load data into Marklogic from MySql database.
As well as how to create a document database & build search application on top of it ? (PDF's would be the source for documents database)

-Thanks & Regards
Swapneel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two main options for loading data from MySQL - you can either export flat csv files and import the rows as documents using [MLCP](https://developer.marklogic.com/products/mlcp) or by connecting directly with [MLSAM](https://developer.marklogic.com/code/mlsam).  You'll have to look and see which best suits your situation.

In terms of design, I'd recommend looking at the MarkLogic developer website and going through the tutorials; there's a good overview of [data modeling](https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/data-modeling).

You will probably want to look at the [CPF documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cpf/default) for information about PDF conversion as well.

Hope that's been useful, Ed